# Rolling sum based on dates, adding in conditions that actively update values in Pandas Dataframe if met?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, rolling-computation

I am calculating rolling last 180 day sales totals by ID in Python using Pandas and need to be able to update the last 180 day cumulative sales column if a user hits a certain threshold.  For example, if someone reaches $100 spent cumulatively in the last 180 days, their cumulative spend for that day should reflect them reaching that level and effectively "redeeming" that $100, leaving them only with the excess from the last visit as progress towards their next $100 hit. (See the example below)

I also need to create a separate data frame during this process containing only the dates & user_ids for when the $100 is met to keep track of how many times the threshold has been met across all users.

I was thinking somehow I could use apply with conditional statements, but was not sure exactly how it would work as the data frame needs to be updated on the fly to have the rolling sums for later dates be calculated taking into account this updated total.  In other words, the cumulative sums for dates after they hit the threshold need to be adjusted for the fact that they "redeemed" the $100.

This is what I have so far that gets the rolling cumulative sum by user.  I don't know if its possible to chain conditional methods with apply to this or what the best way forward is.

```py
order_data['rolling_sales_180'] = order_data.groupby('user_id').rolling(window='180D', on='day')['sales'].sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

See the below example of expected results. In row 6, the user reaches $120, crossing the $100 threshold, but the $100 is subtracted from his cumulative sum as of that date and he is left with $20 as of that date because that was the amount in excess of the $100 threshold that he spent on that day.  He then continues to earn cumulatively on this $20 for his subsequent visit within 180 days.  A user can go through this process many times, earning many rewards over different 180 day periods.

```
print(order_data)

         day  user_id   sales  \
0 2017-08-10      1      10   
1 2017-08-22      1      10   
2 2017-08-31      1      10   
3 2017-09-06      1      10   
4 2017-09-19      1      10   
5 2017-10-16      1      30   
6 2017-11-28      1      40   
7 2018-01-22      1      10   
8 2018-03-19      1      10   
9 2018-07-25      1      10   

   rolling_sales_180  
0              10  
1              20  
2              30  
3              40  
4              50  
5              80  
6              20  
7              30  
8              40  
9              20
```

Additionally, as mentioned above, I need a separate data frame to be created throughout this process with the day, user_id, sales, and rolling_sales_180 that only includes all the days during which the $100 threshold was met in order to count the number of times this goal is reached.  See below:

```
print(threshold_reached)

         day  user_id   sales  rolling_sales_180
0 2017-11-28      1      40        120
.
.
.
```

Comment: Too many words, I'm not even going to start reading that, sorry. Please give a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following should work for you:

```
def groupby_rolling(grp_df):
    df = grp_df.set_index("day")
    cum_sales = df.rolling("180D")["sales"].sum()
    hundreds = (cum_sales // 100).astype(int)
    progress = cum_sales % 100
    df["rolling_sales_180"] = cum_sales
    df["progress"] = progress
    df["milestones"] = hundreds
    return df

result = df.groupby("user_id").apply(groupby_rolling)
```

Output of this is (for your provided sample):

```
                    user_id  sales  rolling_sales_180  progress  milestones
user_id day                                                                
1       2017-08-10        1     10               10.0      10.0           0
        2017-08-22        1     10               20.0      20.0           0
        2017-08-31        1     10               30.0      30.0           0
        2017-09-06        1     10               40.0      40.0           0
        2017-09-19        1     10               50.0      50.0           0
        2017-10-16        1     30               80.0      80.0           0
        2017-11-28        1     40              120.0      20.0           1
        2018-01-22        1     10              130.0      30.0           1
        2018-03-19        1     10               90.0      90.0           0
        2018-07-25        1     10               20.0      20.0           0
```

What the `groupby(...).apply(...)` does is for each group in the original `df`, the provided function is applied. In this case, I've encapsulated your complex logic, which is currently not possible to do with a straightforward groupby-rolling operation, in a simple-to-parse basic function.

The function should hopefully be self-documenting by how I named variables, but I'd be happy to add comments if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so close to what I need! The only thing is that it seems like the total for 2018-03-19 is not recalculating based on the new total for 2017-11-28, which is $20, it seems to still be including spend prior to that that should be wiped out.  In the same vein, 2018-01-22 should not be hitting another milestone, the cum sum is only $30 since prior spend is wiped.  Is it possible to change the columns on the fly while the function is executing? I think that would solve this issue.

Comment: @ll2651 Ah, I see the issue. I'm not sure you can achieve what you're looking for without looping through each group of the dataframe.